# What do I do if I feel I could make a quality additional answer to a closed question?

Tags: discussion

Obviously this is from my perspective, but I had an answer to a question that was closed ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576018/what-is-the-difference-between-a-javascript-framework-and-a-library)) because it was a duplicate of a duplicate and the original was closed because it was too broad.

Maybe it's not worth adding to, but it didn't seem too broad of a question to me as it was within the confines of the Javascript tag.  Again it's my opinion, so I'm open to correction.

Comment: What is the difference between X and Y questions are *(these days)* *rarely* on topic for [so].

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you found good on-topic part of otherwise closed question (i.e. narrow portion of too-broad or specific part of opinion based on) than you can ask new question that asks about that on-topic part and possibly self-answer it. Sometimes you may edit existing question to get it re-opened, but it is unlikely for too-broad or opinion based cases as you'd probably change original author's intent.

Note that in the case of linked "difference between framework and library" question it is very unlikely to find on-topic part to make a new question of it. Feel free to comment with a link to you personal page/blog/whatever where you discuss those concepts if interested.

Comment: I like this, +1. Someone will come along and say that self-answered Q&A should be held to a higher standard. Ignore them. Just remember to reference the old question if you reuse parts, we don't want accusations of plagiarism either.

Comment: Okay, I guess my confusion was over the definition of "too broad" then.  It seemed a narrow enough question to me.  Thanks!

Comment: *didn't seem too broad of a question to me as it was within the confines of the Javascript tag*, the **Too Broad** designation is a **site wide** constraint, tags are irrelevant in the definition of what is **Too Broad**.

Comment: Wait, I suggeted this several times for all closed questions... but somehow people disagreed.

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, I think the question you're talking about is indeed too broad and should not be reopened, but I'll give a general answer for similar scenarios:

If you find a question that you believe should be reopened, you can post a message to the [Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room.

This chat room is mostly used to talk about posts that should be closed, but you can also use it to talk about closed posts that should be reopened.

The general format of your post should use the [reopen-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-pls) tag, like this:

```
[tag:reopen-pls] reason for reopening https://stackoverflow.com/q/12345
```

In your case:

```
[tag:reopen-pls] Post is on-topic for JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/q/11576018/873165
```

This is especially handy when a user improves their post, or somebody edits a post to make it better. Often times people will vote to close a question and never look at it again, so this is handy for helping people who are making an effort to improve their posts.

More info can be found at the Close Vote Reviewers homepage [here](https://socvr.org/).

Comment: Also worth mentioning several tag-specific communities can help with such assessment via their chat rooms. I can't speak for all communities, but `[python]` is certainly active in this regard. The benefit here is you may also get more appropriate treatment, e.g. the community will be more familiar with canonical duplicates.